# JSON Parsing works on Android 4.0 but not on Android < 4.0

Tags: android, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON parsing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254962/json-parsing-problem)

I am parsing a JSON file (Which is valid). It works on Android 4.0 - 4.0.4 but not on older Android versions.
This is a part of my Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

And this is my parsing code:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;

}
```

And on the older devices I get the following error message (But as I said not on new Android devices):

> org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I have absolutely no idea why it does work on Android 4 but not on older devices.

Find the Json from [here](http://pastebin.com/Jp6Z2wmX)

Comment: paste entire json here! or try to validate on www.jsonlint.com.I doubt there is some problem with json.

Comment: As I said (And I now validated again with jsonlint.com) it's a valid json... And the strange thing is, that it works on Android 4...

Comment: Are you sure that the version of org.json library is the same on both devices? Also, increase your buffer size for your buffered reader.

Comment: Yes I executed the exact same build on an emulator and devices running 2.1 and on my cell running 4.0.. Ok will try. But if it works on one why doesnt it on the other?

Comment: what version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: SDK Tools Revision 19 and SDK Platform-Tools Revision 11.

Comment: I have tested your code by using http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Jp6Z2wmX url and your code is working fine without any exception. I have tested your code on API level 2.2 and device 2.2.1 vesrion. In which device you have tested your code?

Comment: Did you log the String you're trying to parse? What if you remove all non-plain ASCII characters from the JSON? Does logging the full exception/stacktrace give you any clue? So: `Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + json, e);` Could the `json` class property be accessed/changed by other threads? (Why not use a local variable instead?)

Comment: Note that the Pastebin URL that @Vivek used, sends the (correct) HTTP header to handle the German characters: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` Are you sure the actual server is doing that too?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't... It just says Content-Type: text/plain. How can I change that? On the server itself?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the `JSONObject` parser has been made more lenient in newer Android releases. The error message you are getting appears to be due to dubiously-legal JSON, particularly on the receiving side:

- [Issue initializing a JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062007/issue-initializing-a-jsonobject)
- [JSON parsing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254962/json-parsing-problem)

I would suggest that you write your downloaded JSON out to a file and compare it with your original to see if there is a problem with the download logic.

---

**UPDATE**

I cannot reproduce your problem. Loading that JSON off of external storage works perfectly fine on Android 4.0.3., 2.3.3, 2.2, and 2.1, using the following activity (note: I was lazy and hard-wired in the path to external storage):

```
package com.commonsware.jsontest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONTestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
      BufferedReader in=
          new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/test.json"));
      String str;
      StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();

      while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
        buf.append(str);
        buf.append("\n");
      }

      in.close();
      JSONObject json=new JSONObject(buf.toString());

      ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.stuff)).setText(json.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception loading file", e);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception parsing file", e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that but it gives the EXACT same file as I have on my server.

Comment: @user754730: At this point, unless you can give us a project that reproduces the error, I doubt anyone can really help you.

Comment: @user754730: Well, we certainly need the JSON that is causing the error.

Comment: @user754730: I'll try to take a look at this sometime in the next 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 2):

Usually these are the following steps to create json object through the Http connection in android.

1. open the connection and get the response.
2. get the content and create a string builder.
3. make the string builder into json array object (this step you have not done)
4. get json object from the json array object.

I think you missed to convert String Buffer(sb) into json array object. Instead of that you directly create the json object from string buffer. I dont know how its was worked in android 4.0.
The modified code is

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
       JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;

}
```

And you can get the json object by passing index value like,

`jObj.getJSONObject(i); /*i is a integer,  index value*/`

Comment: Thanks alot for this approach! Unfortunately this does neither work on 2.1/2.2 not on 4.0 :(

Answer (score 2):

Hello i used the following code and i did not get any errors in 2.2, 2.3.3 code is very simple.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class NannuExpActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            JSONObject jo = getJSONObjectFromUrl("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Jp6Z2wmX");
            for(int i=0;i<jo.getJSONArray("map_locations").length();i++)
            Log.d("Data",jo.getJSONArray("map_locations").getJSONObject(i).getString("title"));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public JSONObject getJSONObjectFromUrl(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
        JSONObject jobj = null;
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> rHand = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String resp = "";
        resp = hc.execute(hGet,rHand);
        jobj = new JSONObject(resp);    
        return jobj;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I used following code for json, for me it support all android version.

```
List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", qry));
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(your url);
request.setEntity(formEntity);

HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(request);
Log.d("UkootLog", "Http status code " + rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK
    || rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 600) {
  Log.d("JsonLog", "Success !!");
  String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
} else {
  Log.d("UkootLog", "Failed while request json !!");
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

the solution here will solve your problem
it's because of the utf-8 encoding coming back from the server.

[JSON parsing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254962/json-parsing-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure why you are getting this error. But I too had come across a similar problem  and it was solved by changing the charSet. Try using `iso-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8`.

Comment: That's actually what I did have before. That doesn't work on either of the Versions :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Jackson?  I've used it on every version of android and it works quite nicely.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the JSONParser?

here is a example wich i use:

```
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 


    try {

        if(jsonString != null)
            json =  (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

    } catch (ParseException e) {        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and used http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Jp6Z2wmX as the input to your `getJSONFromUrl(String url)` method. Interestingly, I was not able to reproduce your issue (with several combinations of AVD and/or target API of 15, 10, or 7).

Some things I do notice:

- `InputStream is`, `String json`, `JSONObject jObj` are declared externally to your `getJSONFromUrl()` method and there is a possibility that they are somehow affected differently by some other part of your code when running on one API compared to another.
- Looking at the exception that you got, it is likely that it is thrown due to the fact that the input `String` to the `JSONObject` constructor is an empty string (""). Is it possible that somehow your server supplied a different data to your older Android?

Here's my suggestions:

- Add the following lines to the top of your `getJSONFromUrl()` method:

  ```
  InputStream is = null;
  String json = null;
  JSONObject jObj = null;
  ```
- Add a line of debug code to print out the downloaded string between the last 2 try-catch blocks, like this:

  ```
  // ----- cut ----
      Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
  }

  Log.d("getJSONFromUrl", "json=(" + json + ")");

  try {
      jObj = new JSONObject(json);
  // ----- cut ----
  ```

I think we will know more about your issue after you make either one or both of the above changes :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!
I did already have those 3 lines in my code before...
I then tried the Logging stuff and it just prints out my complete JSON and then throws the exception as before :(

Comment: Interesting, could you try calling your `getJSONFromUrl(url)` method passing `http://pastebin.com/Jp6Z2wmX` and `http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Jp6Z2wmX` as the `url` value? I would be very curious to see the logcat output from those two if you could put it on pastebin too.

Comment: Wow strange enough it works from pastebin perfectly on 2.2 and 4.0. I have NO idea though why?
So at the moment this is what the situation is like:
Android 4 + our Server = WORKS,
Android < 4 + our Server = DOESN'T WORK,
Android 4 + Pastebin = WORKS,
Android < 4 + Pastebin = WORKS

Comment: Aha :) What server software do you use? I would look into the server logs and maybe even use Wireshark to see track it down at the lower level.

Comment: Wow I still can't really believe it... We have a rented server which runs Apache. Maybe that's the problem? Or should I escape the strange characters (Like ö,ä,ü) from the JSON file?

Comment: Any luck on getting the server logs and/or Wireshark trace? Maybe you can simply try to access your server URL from browser on the Android < 4 device to see if it connects at all.

Comment: Well yes it does connect in the browser itself... It also shows the JSON correctly... I also tried escaping the german umlaute but that didn't  help either... I will keep on trying to find the difference between pastebin and our server though...

Answer (score 1):

Jackson or GSON.

could be the german extra characters in there and an internationalization (i18n) or utf-8 issue.

I would restart Eclipse, do a clean build and try again.

Comment: Did that already.... Maybe escaping the extra characters could help?!

Comment: escaping is a good idea or uuencoding/mime encoding/url encoding

Comment: Tried it... Didn't help either :(

Comment: Restarting Eclipse to get an app work differently on a device? If that often solves issues for you, then I'm afraid your developer environment (and the way you build your apps) needs some proper set up.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of the variable called `json` in the line: `json = sb.toString();`

Is it a String? If it is a `JSONObject`, change its type to `String` and your code will work perfectly.

---

Another remark is the handling of exceptions: It seems that if an exception is thrown in the first block when you building your String, the `JSONObject` initialization will be attempted with some faulty data.

---

Anyway try this (I suspect your download method is buggy):

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    try {
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
        ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
        ResponseHandler<String> res = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
            public String handleResponse(final HttpResponse response) throws HttpResponseException, IOException {
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= 300) {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(
                    statusLine.getStatusCode(),
                    statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                return entity == null ? null : EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            }
        };

        String response = (new DefaultHttpClient()).execute(postMethod, res);
        return new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either on Android 2.2... It does work on Android 4 though...

Answer (score 0):

Surely this will work. In 4.0 android version we have to create asynctask to avoid exception i.e `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ll get. Its working fine for me.

```
public class Http_Get_JsonActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


String d = new Date().toString();

private static final String TAG = "MyPost";

private boolean post_is_running = false;

private doSomethingDelayed doSth;

private String url = "http://192.168.1.1";
private InputStream is;
private String json;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    Button pushButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pushButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (post_is_running) { // stop async task if it's running if app gets
                            // paused
        Log.v(TAG, "Stopping Async Task onPause");
        doSth.cancel(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (post_is_running) {
        // start async task if it was running previously and was stopped by
        // onPause()
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting Async Task onResume");
        doSth = (doSomethingDelayed) new doSomethingDelayed().execute();
        // ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button)).setText("Resuming..");
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    if (post_is_running == false) {
        post_is_running = true;
        Log.v(TAG, "Starting Async Task onClick");
        doSth = (doSomethingDelayed) new doSomethingDelayed().execute();

        // ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button)).setText("Starting..");
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Stopping Async Task onClick");
        post_is_running = false;
        doSth.cancel(true);
        // ((Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button)).setText("Stopping..");
    }
}

private class doSomethingDelayed extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private int num_runs = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... gurk) {

        // while (!this.isCancelled()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "going into postData");

        long ms_before = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Log.v(TAG, "Time Now is " + ms_before);

        postData();

        Log.v(TAG, "coming out of postData");

        publishProgress(num_runs);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Cancelled BG-Thread";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... num_runs) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to send data to the server
 */

public void postData() {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
        System.out.println("--httppost----" + httpPost);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println("--httpResponse----" + httpResponse);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        System.out.println("--httpEntity----" + httpEntity);
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
        System.out.println("--is----" + is);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        System.out.println("--jObjt--" + jObj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

}

}
```

enjoy..