# response in unreadable format

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

```
var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity
        httpc.open("POST", url, true); // sending as POST
        httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the
            // state changes.
            if (httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) {
            //MY JSON RESPONSE  
                        alert(JSON.stringify(httpc.responseText));
            }
        }
        httpc.send(params);
```

The above code is working fine in android 4.0 and response is getting in valid JSON format..
but when i run the same code in  android 2.3 i'm getting response in unknown format and my url and params are same for both android versions.

**in 2.3 my response is** .
�`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�����iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{���{��;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��?�YQ~�裏F�������n���/����ț&����2���u�~����)`�U��TH��2Ϛ<}S_��Y��z:%�����,�o�e��tv��X��E��{?v��U��V�j�B�s�FU�~�p�Զ�ɢ�i�2[^�i�S��W���_���'������

**in 4.0 my response is** 
[{"email":"","password":"","user_id":"","store_id":"","message":"Alert!, Wrong Email or Password Please Try Again.","success":"0","nick_name":"","magazine_genre_id":"","magazine_genre_name":"","newspaper_genre_id":"","newspaper_genre_name":"","old_password":"","new_password":"","mode":"","languagecode":"","URL":""}] at file:///android_asset/www/project.js:717

**Logcat exception:** SyntaxError: Parse error at undefined:1

Comment: Provide input, output, and expected output, and also specify your `callbackFn`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan ya its updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `responseType` to `json`. I have only used it from jquery. If you have any doubt check this [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#responseType)

**Answer**
There are some alternatives provided in this SO post [JSON Parsing works on Android 4.0 but not on Android < 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064244/json-parsing-works-on-android-4-0-but-not-on-android-4-0)

Comment: oh sorry, i am not an Android programmers, but have you checked this SO post [JSON Parsing works on Android 4.0 but not on Android < 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064244/json-parsing-works-on-android-4-0-but-not-on-android-4-0) Some alternatives are provided there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are doing the opposite thing.

You want to parse a JSON string into an object, not extracting a JSON string FROM an object, which is what JSON.stringify() does.

Use JSON.parse() instead. Also eval() would do the job, but is slow and dis-recommended.

Comment: thank you.. but the issue is not abt json, i'm not getting valid response