# Json work nice on Android ICS but don't work on 2.3

Tags: android, json, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

```
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }    
// try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
         // convert string to jsonObject
        Log.d("JSON Parser", "json: "+json);
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

the `Log.d("JSON Parser", "json: "+json);` give as output (logcat):

```
02-02 12:08:31.371: D/JSON Parser(407): json: {"code":64,"message":"Segnalazione avvenuta con successo"}
```

but it go in the catch and in logcat i read:

```
02-02 12:08:31.371: E/JSON Parser(407): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This work very nice in Android ICS but don't work in Android 2.3

edit: i resolve with

```
if (result.startsWith("["))
  {



  }
  else
  {
      result= result.substring(1);
  }
```

but i don't think it is a correct strategy.

Comment: have you tried it after changing  `sb.append(line + "\n");` to  `sb.append(line);`

Comment: i tried but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `responseType` to `json`. If the issue still exists there are some suggestions in these posts
 [JSON Parsing works on Android 4.0 but not on Android < 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064244/json-parsing-works-on-android-4-0-but-not-on-android-4-0)
 [Issue initializing a JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062007/issue-initializing-a-jsonobject)
 [JSON parsing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254962/json-parsing-problem)

Comment: i am trying to follow the answer but don't understand what is:  `utf8 = Response.toCharArray();` What is Response?

Comment: He's asking about Javascript, not Java.