# JSONObject not working for Android 2.3 but works fine with Android 4.2, why?

Tags: android, json

I am requesting server for a JSONObject and it contains a list of some ids. This is working fine with Android 4.2 but not working with Android 2.3 (have tested on both Device and Emulator.)

The JSONObject is as follows.

```
{"IdList":[{"id":"004502"},{"id":"S007901"},{"id":"041501"},{"id":"S139001"}]}
```

This works fine with 4.2, but shows `NullPointerException` in 2.3.

My LogCat is as follows:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value Nullpointer of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-06 11:23:46.881: W/System.err(1820):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
06-06 11:23:46.893: W/System.err(1820):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
06-06 11:23:46.893: W/System.err(1820):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
06-06 11:23:46.893: W/System.err(1820):     at my.Site.serverInterface.executeHttpRequest(serverInterface.java:128)
06-06 11:23:46.893: W/System.err(1820):     at my.Site.serverInterface.getAtmId(serverInterface.java:54)
06-06 11:23:46.901: W/System.err(1820):     at my.Site.TrackLocation$AtmGetter.doInBackground(TrackLocation.java:379)
06-06 11:23:46.901: W/System.err(1820):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-06 11:23:46.901: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-06 11:23:46.901: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-06 11:23:46.901: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-06 11:23:46.901: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-06 11:23:46.901: W/System.err(1820):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-06 11:23:46.901: I/System.out(1820): null
06-06 11:23:46.912: I/System.out(1820)://e
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820):     at my.Site.TrackLocation$AtmGetter.doInBackground(TrackLocation.java:384)
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-06 11:23:46.912: W/System.err(1820):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-06 11:23:46.921: W/dalvikvm(1820): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb60c84f0)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at my.Site.TrackLocation$AtmGetter.doInBackground(TrackLocation.java:427)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-06 11:23:46.931: E/AndroidRuntime(1820):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: When initializing JSONObject keeps it null.

Comment: You are getting NullPointerException in doinBackgroung method. Better you print the json response in onPost method the start parse.

Comment: @VarunVishnoi and sunil .. not working.

Comment: if u post code we can help further.

Comment: hmmm thats weird, I tested with 2.3.3 emulator and it was good. Post code so we can get you going!

Comment: Provide some code. Then only we can tell about it.

Comment: public static JSONObject getId(String user) {
  SERVER_URL=DOMAIN_NAME+"getids.jsp";
  String data="username="+URLEncoder.encode(user);

  System.out.println(executeHttpRequest(data));  //this line was causing the problem


  return executeHttpRequest(data);



 }

Comment: I removed that println statement and its working fine.

Comment: hi have you find solution? Please suggest me i have got this error...

Comment: post the json parsing code. post the code where the exception is thrown. post the actual JSON string (from both platforms). (log it before parsing it)

Comment: [{"status":"true","General":[{"images":"aaa"}],"Category":[{"images":"aaa"}]}]



Json Parse using below line

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseData);

Error :
org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: check your jsonParser class, that what it return. Is it **string** or **JSONObejct** ?

Comment: change System.out.println(executeHttpRequest(data)); to System.out.println("" + executeHttpRequest(data)); if on this line you are getting null pointer.

Comment: I think you are getting JSONArray not jason object, so try with JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Just import json library files to your project
http://www.json.org/java/index.html
https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/downloads/list

Comment: not working.. Why does this not working in 2.3 ?   It works fine in 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

download the org.json jar and import it. It should work for 2.3 also.

Refer this ..

[JSON Parsing works on Android 4.0 but not on Android < 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064244/json-parsing-works-on-android-4-0-but-not-on-android-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `responseType` to `json`. If the issue still exists there are some suggestions in these posts

[JSON Parsing works on Android 4.0 but not on Android < 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064244/json-parsing-works-on-android-4-0-but-not-on-android-4-0)

[Issue initializing a JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062007/issue-initializing-a-jsonobject)

[JSON parsing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254962/json-parsing-problem)